# Xcode no reconoce mi dispositivo

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iphone

Estoy tratando de compilar mi proyecto de Xcode en mi iPad, pero estoy recibiendo un error que dice que mi iPad no puede ser reconocido, el dispositivo esta actualizado a la última versión de `IOS 9.2`.

Al principio me dio un error diciendo Xcode no se puede ejecutar el dispositivo seleccionado, luego quité mi dispositivo y lo conecté de nuevo porque no estaba seguro de qué hacer.

También intenté probar mi proyecto usando en un iPhone y el error que me dieron era diferente. El error, dijo: **No code signing identities found**, no estoy preocupado por el error de que me dio el iPhone porque mi aplicación fue basada para el iPad.

Limpié el proyecto y reinicie Xcode para ver si eso lo arreglaría, pero nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué tenés cuando seleccionas el proyecto, después el Target y después en General -> identity? Muchas veces, tenés que darle de alta al dispositivo a través de Xcode para que lo puedas usar.

Answer (score 2):

Para compilar con Xcode en un dispositivo con la versión 9.2 necesitas tener Xcode 7.2 instalado. Probablemente sea ese tu problema, que has actualizado iOS pero no Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Toma en cuenta que:

- Tienes que crear un certificado provisional de desarrollo para hacer
  tus pruebas
- En tus perfiles tienes que autorizar tu iPhone, iPad
  para esa aplicación en especifica

Tambien prueba descargando el XCode Beta

Answer (score 0):

Para desarrollar y compilar con la ultima versión disponible de iOS especialmente si es una actualización reciente es muy probable que necesites también la ultima versión de Xcode, recordar también que para compilar una aplicación en un dispositivo necesitas contar con la licencia de desarrollador.